# Use Parse as the backend for Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parse-platform

We are trying to build a `Rails App` with `Parse` as the backend. On investigation we found `parse_resource` that can be used. But it does not seem to be well maintained or have good enough support. Should we go ahead with it or there is some other alternative for this.

Any suggestions is highly appreciated!

Comment: There is one more `parse-ruby-client` but I am not sure which way to go.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."